# Jquery Onclick on Iphone devices

Tags: jquery, iphone, asp.net-mvc, html, mobile

I'm using MVC on my website and I have troubles using a "onclick" on a form. Here is my code :

```
using (@Html.BeginForm("findpost", "keyword", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "mainForm" }))
                    {
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit" name="s" onclick="showupdate();"></button>
                        <input name="query" type="text" id="query" value="@Model.search" placeholder=" ex: iPod">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pos" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="dis" value="" />
                    }
```

The showupdate(); shows a gif during the loading of the result page. This is working just fine on desktop & android device. The search has strange behavior on iphones. It only takes into account the first keyword I enter (from the homepage). If I remove the "onclick=...", it works but it doesn't load the gif ...
Any idea where could come from ? I tried to add the click directly in JS but it doesn't work neither.

Here is the gif :

```
function preparepreloader() {
var loader = $('<div class="preloaderwrapper hiddenn">' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="preloader hiddenn">' +
    '<div class="prewrapper">' +
        '<div class="eyeglass">' +
            '&nbsp;</div>' +
        '<div class="preloaderanimate">' +
            '&nbsp;</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>');

var new_loader = $('<div class="preloader_gif preloader hiddenn"> <img src="'+ mediaUrl +'/img/loader/712.gif" /> </div>');

$('#updatepreloader').append(loader);
$('#updatepreloader').append(new_loader);}
```

Comment: Is the GIF already in the body (hidden) or do you append it after using the showupdate() function?

Comment: This is an "append". There is some check before but I can add the code.

Comment: the problem is that you're trying to load an image when you submit the form, so what do you want that the browser load first?! You have to way to do it: Place the div "preloaderwrapper" as hidden in the body and with you function you just show it, or prevent the default event, build the div and then go on with the submit default event. I'll try to write an answer asap.

Comment: Another stuff, you're calling **showupdate()** but you posted **preparepreloader() **... I get lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a class **hasLoader** for the forms you want to show your gif after submit, so you can prevent the default event, load the gif, and then the form will be submitted automatically after. Sorry, but I got confused with **showupdate()** and **preparepreloader()** so I hope that was the some stuff has I understood.

**MVC**

```
using (@Html.BeginForm("findpost", "keyword", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "mainForm", @class = "hasLoader" }))
{
    <button type="submit" class="btn-submit" name="s"></button>
    <input name="query" type="text" id="query" value="@Model.search" placeholder=" ex: iPod">
    <input type="hidden" name="pos" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="dis" value="" />
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.hasLoader').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loader = $('<div class="preloaderwrapper hiddenn"></div>' +
    '<div class="preloader hiddenn">' +
        '<div class="prewrapper">' +
            '<div class="eyeglass">&nbsp;</div>' +
            '<div class="preloaderanimate">&nbsp;</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>');

    var new_loader = $('<div class="preloader_gif preloader hiddenn"> <img src="'+ mediaUrl +'/img/loader/712.gif" /> </div>');

    $('#updatepreloader').append(loader, new_loader);
    $(this).off('submit').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't put all my code, only the essential but you get the idea! This was helpfull!

Comment: You're welcome! But please, just for me, can you please tell me if **showupdate()** and **preparepreloader()** were the same function?

Comment: In fact, showupdate() just makes some basics checks (null or empty keyword and some basic sutff like that) then calls prepareloader.